# React Native: Navigating between nested navigators from different components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building an app with one main tab navigator, and then several nested stack navigators within it. All of my navigators are written within the `App.js` file. The main tab navigator is working fine, however when I attempt to navigate into one of the nested stack navigators I get a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.props.navigation)` error.

Here is an example of my code below:

**App.js File**

```
    import React from 'react;
    import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
    import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
    import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import Home from './src/screens/Home';
    import Settings from './src/screens/Settings';
    import Privacy from './src/screens/Privacy';

    const PrivacyStack = createStackNavigator();
    const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
    const Tabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

    const TabNavigator = () => {
     return (
    <Tabs.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    <Tabs.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeStack}
    />
    Tabs.Screen
    name="Settings"
    component={SettingsStack}
    children={this.SettingsStack}
    </Tabs.Navigator>
    )
    }

const AuthStack = () => (
  <AuthStack.Navigator>
    <AuthStack.Screen
      name="Auth"
      component={Auth}
    />
  </AuthStack.Navigator>
);


    const SettingsStackScreen = () => (
      <SettingsStack.Navigator>
        <SettingsStack.Screen
          name="Settings"
          component={Settings}
        />
        <SettingsStack.Screen
          name="Privacy"
          component={PrivacyStack}

        />
      </SettingsStack.Navigator>
    );

    const PrivacyStack = () => (
      <PrivacyStack.Navigator>
        <PrivacyStack.Screen
          name="Privacy"
          component={Privacy}
        />
        <PrivacyStack.Screen
          name="Notifications"
          component={Notifications}

        />
      </PrivacyStack.Navigator>
    );

const App = () => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <MainStack.Navigator>
        <MainStack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigator} />
        <MainStack.Screen
          name="Auth"
          component={AuthStack}
          options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
        />
      </MainStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
}
```

**Settings.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native;

const Settings = (navigation, props) => {
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PrivacyStack', {screen: 'Privacy'}
)
}
</TouchableOpacity>

export default Settings
```

**Privacy.js File**

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native;

const Privacy = (navigation, props) => {
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications'
)
}
</TouchableOpacity>

export default Privacy
```

After the user has passed auth, they are taken to the `MainStack` which has a bottom tab navigator with a `Home` screen option, and a `Settings` screen option. **This part is all currently working fine**. However once I click the `<TouchableOpacity>` on the `Settings` screen I get the error.

I suspect it must be an issue with the way I am using `this.props.navigation` however I have not managed to figure out the problem through my own troubleshooting. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using functional component so you can use the navigation like below

```
const Settings = (props) => {
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('PrivacyStack',
```

'navigation' is passed as a prop and will reside inside props argument.

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked. If I am using a class component, do I then use the `this.props.navigation`?